# Getting JasperSoft's iReport to play nice with subreports and page breaks

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have a report with two subreports. The first subreport is very short, the second one is quite long. I would like the exported spreadsheet to have a single sheet/tab for each of these two subreports.

In the main report's layout, the two subreports separated by a page break.

When I export (or just view the html in the browser), the page break appears after the first subreport, but the second one is then chopped into several more pages (because its very long).

Now I could make the main report a million pixels in height, but that would be an ugly hack making the first subreport appear with data in the first 10 rows and followed by thousands of empty rows.

How can I fix this?

(It is driving me mad.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the report has a property called "Ignore Pagination" (iReport 4.0.2). If checked, it will print the whole document as a single page.

[image: Properties Pane - Ignore Pagination]